# Create custom messages for expired and locked user

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I want to return custom message if user during authentication process is locked or expired. I tried to implement this:

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsHandler implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UsersService usersService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        final Optional<Users> user = usersService.findByLogin(username);

        if (!user.isPresent()) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User '" + username + "' not found");
        }

        return user
            .map(value -> {
                return new User(
                        value.getLogin(),
                        value.getEncryptedPassword(),
                        value.getEnabled(),
                        hasAccountExpired(value.getExpiredAt()),
                        hasPasswordExpired(value.getPasswordChangedAt()),
                        hasAccountLocked(value.getLockedAt()),
                        Collections.singleton(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(value.getRole().getAuthority()))
                );
            }).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User with username " + username + " not found"));
    }

    private boolean hasAccountExpired(LocalDateTime account_expired_at) {

        return account_expired_at == null;
    }
```

Full code: [GitHub](https://github.com/rcbandit111/wiki/blob/master/src/main/java/org/engine/security/UserDetailsHandler.java)

The question is how to create handlers which return some custom message if the validation returns true value for statuses `user locked` or `user expired`?

Comment: create a custom exception for instance `UserLockedException`, then catch this exception in a `@ControllerAdvice` annotated class and map it to a custom response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option for you is:

1. Implement Spring `UserDetails` in your entity `Users`.
2. Check in `loadUserByUsername` if the user has been locked, etc using Spring `AccountStatusUserDetailsChecker` class.
3. Add into your `EngineExceptionHandler` the required methods to manage those exceptions: `LockedException`, `AccountExpiredException`, etc

You will see examples of above points in the following links:

[Point 1](https://github.com/doctore/Spring5Microservices/blob/master/security-oauth-service/src/main/java/com/security/oauth/model/User.java)

[Point 2](https://github.com/doctore/Spring5Microservices/blob/master/security-oauth-service/src/main/java/com/security/oauth/service/UserService.java)

[Points 2-3](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/AccountStatusUserDetailsChecker.java)

Comment: I have included the required code for the first 2 steps (suitable examples easy to adapt). For the 3rd one, you have to include new methods in your `EngineExceptionHandler` to manage the exceptions that `AccountStatusUserService.check()` will throw for the use cases you mention: `LockedException` and `AccountExpriredException` (take a look to the third link to see when those ones are throwed)

Comment: for 1) Is it a good practice to add the valuation logic like this: https://pastebin.com/sNK7xHLT

Comment: The implementation of required methods of `UserDetails`: `isAccountNotLocked`, etc depends of your use case. Here you can see a detailed explanation of everyone: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html  . It is a good practice include an implementation of that interface in your model, if it matches with the entity you are using to manage your users because, as you can see, is more easy to use the functionality provided by Spring.

Comment: What if I create a new Interface similar to `UserDetails`?  only for several values? Is it going to work similar to the examples that you showed me?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean. `UserDetails` is an Spring interface, is not a "custom one". You can create if you want another similar without problems, but the advantage in this case is to use it, because Spring will provide you several functionality to work with it (like `AccountStatusUserService`).

Comment: If you have, for example, several types of users in your application, with different entities, database tables etc then it could be a good approach create a hierarchy with them, on which, the "parent class" implements `UserDetails` and contains only the common properties. And every "child class" implements the required methods in the required way.

Comment: I'm stacked with one issue here: https://github.com/rcbandit111/wiki/pull/16/commits/3776df904c96de732b5d0e0394a9b51fdb521f71#diff-1050d114a7c5a5728dbd26bde6815707R32  I get Required type:
UserDetails
Provided:
Users   Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: Why did you create your own `AccountStatusUserDetailsChecker` instead of use the existing one provided by Spring? Why did you implements `UserDetails` in `InvestmentOpportunities` instead of in `Users`? `(value = "userChecksService")` is not required in your case, that is the default value.

Comment: `AccountStatusUserDetailsChecker.check(UserDetails user)` however, in your `loadByUsername` you are using and instance of `Users`, that "currently" doesn't implement `UserDetails` interface (you have included it on `InvestmentOpportinities`, why?)

Comment: My mistake, I fixed it. By looking at the code is it going to work? I don't have a running FE app to test it.

Comment: That part of the code, yes. I have no idea about the other ones. Basically, you can test it without any FE application in two ways: doing tests in your code (Junit, integration, etc), test your flow manually using a Rest client like `postman` (or any other similar)

Comment: One more question: looks like there is one additional SQL made in order to get the data for the checks. I saw into your example code that you have implemented caching. Is there some way to use only one SQL query for the entire authentication process and users checks?

Comment: Why an additional query is executed? In the "new version" there is the same query to database than in your "old one" (`UserDetailsHandler.java`), in both cases, you are getting the user's information from database by `username`. Are you using "old" and "new" services at the same time?

Comment: Regarding to cache, yes, I use it for different purposes in different microservices I have developed, however, the method should be invoked only in a "login request" and you should receive the "actual information". If you want to use a cache for that then you have to develop a way to clean it when "someone" updates the user's information in database.

Answer (score 1):

Well I briefly look at your codes and you implement a `JwtTokenFilter` that will some how calls the `UserDetailsHandler` .

In  `JwtTokenFilter` , you already catch and handle `EngineException` which contain the HTTP status codes and a message. An HTTP response will be sent out which the status and the body message that are the same as what defined in the caught `EngineException`

It seems that you already configure everything for it to work , so just simply throw `EngineException` with the suitable HTTP status code and message from the `UserDetailsHandler` . Something like :

```java
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
         Users user = usersService.findByLogin(username)
                    .map(value -> {
                        return new User(
                            value.getLogin(),
                            value.getEncryptedPassword(),
                            value.getEnabled(),
                            hasAccountExpired(value.getExpiredAt()),
                            hasPasswordExpired(value.getPasswordChangedAt()),
                            hasAccountLocked(value.getLockedAt()),
                            Collections.singleton(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(value.getRole().getAuthority()))
                    ).orElseThrow(()-> throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User '" + username + "' not found"));

             if (user.isAccountLock()){
                throw new EngineException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED , "Custom message for account lock ......")
             }

             if(user.isAccountExpired()){
                throw new EngineException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED , "Custom message for account expired... ......")
             }

    }
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but first this will create a new user session and then throw error. Maybe we need to change the order of the checks?

Comment: what do you mean user session ? do you mean HttpSession ? But your configuration is set to `SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS` which will not create any session for the authenticated user. I don't see there are any difference if you rearrange the order of checking the account is locked and if it is expired

Comment: hm... probably when `User` object is created using `new User` it will create a JWT token?

Comment: the JWT token is specified by the client who call the API in the http request header . It is not created by your application , so it will not created when you call any codes in your application include `new User` ...

Answer (score 1):

Spring Security uses the `messages.properties` which consist of *default messages*, we can add our custom message with the same. Add `messages.properties` and add a message as shown below.

```
AccountStatusUserDetailsChecker.expired=User account has expired
AccountStatusUserDetailsChecker.locked=User account is locked
AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.expired=User account has expired
AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.locked=User account is locked
```

You may find the default messages [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/security/messages.properties)

Answer (score 1):

Its simple 2 steps approach. User expired means token expired

**Step 1**
Modify `JWTTokenProvider` Class to add a custom header to Http Servlet Request using `setAttribute()` method.

```
JwtTokenProvider.java

public boolean validateToken(String token,HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest){
        try {
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(SECRET).parseClaimsJws(token);
            return true;
        }catch (SignatureException ex){
            System.out.println("Invalid JWT Signature");
        }catch (MalformedJwtException ex){
            System.out.println("Invalid JWT token");
        }catch (ExpiredJwtException ex){
            System.out.println("Expired JWT token");
            httpServletRequest.setAttribute("expired",ex.getMessage());
        }catch (UnsupportedJwtException ex){
            System.out.println("Unsupported JWT exception");
        }catch (IllegalArgumentException ex){
            System.out.println("Jwt claims string is empty");
        }
        return false;
}
```

**Step 2**

Modify commence method in `JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint.class` to check expired header in http servlet request header that we added in step 1.

```
JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint.java

@Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                         HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                         AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException {

        final String expired = (String) httpServletRequest.getAttribute("expired");
        System.out.println(expired);
        if (expired!=null){
            httpServletResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,expired);
        }else{
            httpServletResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,"Invalid Login details");
        }
}
```

It is a best practice to return **detailed error messages** in any REST API. We used this to customize spring rest jwt token expired response to return more detailed error response. We can use this method not only for token expired but also for other jwt token exceptions like `SignatureException`, `Malformed JwtException`, `UnsupportedJwtException` and `IllegalArgumentException`.